# Google Chrome "Override Pages" Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make simple extension to redirect newtab to other online URL. Code below works if I redirect to whatever local page inside the extension's folder.

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "newtab.html"
},
```

but I would like to use external/online URL and if I simply put within the quotes like below it wont work as it's not allowed by chrome.

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "https://stackoverflow.com/"
},
```

so I tried using JavaScript's different ways within the newtab.html, one example below

```
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
```

but this is not working either. Any ideas as to how else I could make it work?

Comment: Is the `window.location.href = ...` code in its own `.js` file? Inline `<script>window.location.href = ...</script>` in an HTML file will not run in a Chrome extension due to security restrictions.

Comment: That was it, it now works, thank you